# Angular router. How to navigate to current URL but with different parameters?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, url-routing

I have a Angular 5 project where users navigate to routes like this when clicking on an item.

```
my_domain/{account_id}/item/{item_id}/open/
my_domain/{account_id}/item/{item_id}/closed/
my_domain/{account_id}/item/{item_id}/snoozed/
```

Users should be able to change the account_id or item_id. So I want to be able to reload the page only changing the parametes (the ids). How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6):

Angular 8

in **.component.ts**
You can use current url and put param to navigate array

```
this.router.navigate([this.router.url, 'open']);
```

or in **.component.html**
You can use dot as part of url "./youparam" - in this case "./" == current url

```
< a [routerLink]="['./open']">open</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
export class YourComponent{
  constructor(public router: Router) {

  }
  ...
  myRouteMethod(accountId, itemId, endpointUrl){
    // Use String literals
    this.router.navigate([`/${accountId}/item/${itemId}/${endpointUrl}/`]);
  }
}
```

On your HTML you can have:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div (click)="myRouteMethod(accountIdSomehow, itemIdSomeHow, 'open')">
open </div>
<div (click)="myRouteMethod(accountIdSomehow, itemIdSomeHow, 'close')"> close </div>
<div (click)="myRouteMethod(accountIdSomehow, itemIdSomeHow, 'other')"> other </div>
</div>
```

It would be useful to know how you're getting accountId and itemId.
Reusable functions will help out, always think of parameters instead of repetition, the trick is adjusting your templates to work dynamically with your component.

Comment: Yeah but the thing is that i would have to do that  three times (for closed, snoozed and open), but I don't want to. I need a way so that it works for any possible URL.

Comment: Maybe you can add how you're currently setting those urls in order to get more insight into your intended purpose. You can add an additional parameter `(accountId, itemId, endpoint)` and modify the navigate as: `.navigate([`/${accountId}/item/${itemId}/${endpoint}/`])`